# Drupal 7: The version of the mpdf library could not be detected

Tags: drupal-7, mpdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to add PDF library in drupal 7.

1. I downloaded the mpdf module and enabled it sucessfully.
2. I downloaded the mPDF library from https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/tree/master and unzipped into `sites/all/libraries` folder and renamed forlder to **`mpdf`**. But report status is still showing that library not found.

[image]

Problem: I want to generate a PDF from HTML node.

Question: What is the correct way to add this **mPDF** library in drupal 7?

Note: My PHP version is 7^. Which seems everything is correct with php and library version (but not sure).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [PDF using mPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf) module you have to download mpdf version 6.1.0

Just download the zip file by using this [MPDF link](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases/download/v6.1.0/01-mPDF-v6.1.0.zip) and unzip it in **sites/all/libraries/mpdf**.

Hope this helps you :)